# Protoc: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: c++, linux

Сразу после установки компилятора для Protocol Buffers при компиляции файла формата выдается ошибка (Ubuntu Linux):

> protoc: error while loading shared libraries: libprotoc.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Как исправить?

Comment: Жи:
 
    protoc: error while loading shared libraries: libprotoc.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

"Возникла ошибка при подгрузке общих библиотек...невозможно открыть объект файла: Такого файла нет!"

Проверьте пути!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Известная проблема](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/issues/detail?id=213). Решается так:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/
```